# Why is one part of the code assuming that the list was expanded, while the other doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read the input from a .txt file and output to another. The 'create' command given by the user adds a patient to the list, and the 'remove' is supposed to delete them if such character exists. The 'list' function outputs all the characters saved.

The issue is that the remove function always gives the result 'Patient could not be removed due to absence' even if it was actually added before. I can understand that it was successfully appended to the list since it does appear in the result when the 'list' function is used.

```
input_file = open('doctors_aid_inputs.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('doctors_aid_outputs.txt', 'w')
read = input_file.readlines()

# Break down the commands so that they indicate one list each, allowing us to handle them seperately
mainList = []
for line in read:
    if line[-1] == '\n':
        command = line[:-1].split()
    else:
        command = line.split()
    mainList.append(command)

frameList = []
for i in mainList:
    if i[0] == 'create':
        patientName = i[1][:-1]
        accuracy = i[2]
        diseaseName = i[3]
        incidence = i[4]
        treatment = i[5]
        risk = i[6]
        if i not in frameList:
            frameList.append(i)
            output_file.write('Patient ' + patientName + ' is recorded.\n')
        else:
            output_file.write('Patient ' + patientName + ' cannot be created due to duplication.\n')
    elif i[0] == 'remove':
        patientName = i[1]
        if i in frameList:
            frameList.remove(i)
            output_file.write('Patient ' + patientName + ' is removed.\n')
        else:
            output_file.write('Patient ' + patientName + ' cannot be removed due to absence.\n')
    elif i[0] == 'list':
        output_file.write('Patient           Diagnosis         Disease           Disease            Treatment              Treatment          \n')
        output_file.write('Name              Accuracy          Name              Incidence          Type                   Risk               \n')
        output_file.write('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
        for j in range(len(frameList)):
            for k in range(1, len(frameList[j])):
                output_file.write(str(frameList[j][k]) + ' ' * (18 - len(frameList[j][k])))
            if k == len(frameList[j]) - 1:
                output_file.write('\n')
```

The input file is like this:
create Hayriye, 0.999, Breast Cancer, 50/100000, Surgery, 0.40
create Deniz, 0.9999, Lung Cancer, 40/100000, Radiotherapy, 0.50
create Ateş, 0.99, Thyroid Cancer, 16/100000, Chemotherapy, 0.02
create Toprak, 0.98, Prostate Cancer, 21/100000, Hormonotherapy, 0.20
create Hypatia, 0.9975, Stomach Cancer, 15/100000, Immunotherapy, 0.04
create Pakiz, 0.9997, Colon Cancer, 14/100000, Targeted Therapy, 0.30
list
remove Ateş
...

Patient Hayriye is recorded.
Patient Deniz is recorded.
Patient Ateş is recorded.
Patient Toprak is recorded.
Patient Hypatia is recorded.
Patient Pakiz is recorded.
[the list containing all the patients added]
**Patient Ateş cannot be removed due to absence.**
Normally it should say 'Patient Ateş is removed' and delete it from the list of patients.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are appending one array to the frameList but then you are trying to find a different array which has almost the same values.

For example: you are adding an array like this: ["create", "Marcus", ...]
Then you are trying to find in frameList something like ["remove", "Marcus", ...].

You could try to append an array without the first element which indicates the action. And search in frameList an array without the first element. In this case, the arrays should be the same and it should work.